# Как сделать кнопку активной если число символов выше 6? Помогите

Tags: jquery, keypress

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.input').on('keypress', function (event) {
       if (event.length > 6){
           $('#button').attr('disabled', false);
       }
       else (event.length < 6)
        $('#button').attr('disabled', true);




   })

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("input").keyup(function(){
    $("button").attr('disabled', $(this).val().length < 6);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input/>
<button>test</button>
```

Comment: Благодарю Вам !!